# Adding points, which are determined by rows, by specific names on the table

Tags: microsoft-excel

Quick disclaimer that I have no experience with excel, so guidelines about what to study to make this simple program would be more than appreciated.

Column A has information about "points" (or placements, in this case), which every value with that row will share. Values would be names, found multiple times over the sheet. Some cells would be empty. I would like to add points whenever same name appears, and sort the names according to how much points they've earned.

So something like this (I'm not sure where to place that result)

|  | List A | List B | List C | Result: |  | Points |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15 | Brian | Jane |  |  | Jane | 27 |
| 12 | Jane | David | Lloyd |  | Brian | 15 |
|  |  |  |  |  | David | 12 |
|  |  |  |  |  | Lloyd | 12 |

For practical uses... You can think of this as a simpler version of list-aggregating sites like TheyShootPictures. How can I implement this with excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use Power Query.

Select the data range, right click it > Get Data from Table and Range.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EYUF.jpg)

Then select ListA, ListB and List C, choose Unpivot Columns in Transform tab. The nambe will be in "Value" column by default.

[image]

Choose Value column > Click Group By in Home tab.

[image]

We set the data is grouped by Value, and the new cloumn (Point) get the results of people's sum of points.

[image]

Choose Point column, click Sort from highest to lowest.

[image]

At last, you can click File > Close and Load To.

Answer (score 0):

Adapt the formula below. It uses the [SUMPRODUCT](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sumproduct-function-16753e75-9f68-4874-94ac-4d2145a2fd2e) function to calculate the sum based on the provided criteria.

> The SUMPRODUCT function returns the sum of the products of corresponding ranges or arrays. The default operation is multiplication, but addition, subtraction, and division are also possible.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$D$3=F2)*($A$2:$A$3))
```

[image: Results]

**DEMO**

[image]